# AtTask API - Adding Time Off Hours

Tags: php, api, rest, soap, attask

I'm using the Chrome Advanced Rest Client to test the AtTask API.  I'm getting a lot of stuff figured out, but also getting some unexpected results.  The latest is when adding new records to the AtTask Time  Off Calendar.

I am able to easily add time off to the calendar.   I am use the POST method, with the following URL:

```
https://COMPANY.attasksandbox.com/attask/api/v4.0/resvt?sessionID=SESSIONIDGOESHERE&userID=USERIDGOESHERE&startDate=2014-11-24T00:00:00&endDate=2014-11-28T23:59:59
```

This mark all the days between 11/24 through 11/28 as time off.  Great, so far.  The problem is that it removes all other rime-off records for the specified user.  I am not issuing a DELETE, so I'm not understanding whey the records are being deleted.  More importantly, I'm not understanding how to keep them from being deleted.

Once again, thanks in advance.

Comment: Has anyone successfully added Time Off Hours through the API?  Is there a bug in the API that causes it to delete all previous records?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Time-off in attask is stored as a collection and when you make an edit to a collection it will replace the collection data with the date provided in the update. This is why your call is removing existing data.

In order to add a new time-off you will need to make 2 calls 1 to get exsisting time-off and one to enter the data back with the new dates.

note-I am using my own data so dates are a bit different for me but concept is same

Your get call will be

```
GET  /api/resvt/search?userID=[userID]&fields=endDate,startDate,ID
```

which returns something like

{

```
"data": [
    {
        "ID": "547debb6000dea62198bd66b7c73e174",
        "objCode": "RESVT",
        "endDate": "2014-07-08T23:59:00:163-0600",
        "startDate": "2014-07-08T00:00:00:163-0600"
    },
    {
        "ID": "547debb6000dea61b8c695ba24918fe8",
        "objCode": "RESVT",
        "endDate": "2014-02-13T23:59:00:329-0700",
        "startDate": "2014-02-13T00:00:00:329-0700"
    }
]
```

}

Once you have this you can add your new time off to the collection using an updates command on the user object. Notice you are providing IDs to the time-off that is already in the system and the new time-Off you are providing no ID

```
PUT /attask/api/v4.0/user/[userID]?&sessionID=[sessionID]&updates={reservedTimes: [ { "ID": "547debb6000dea62198bd66b7c73e174", "objCode": "RESVT", "endDate": "2014-07-08T23:59:00:163-0600", "startDate": "2014-07-08T00:00:00:163-0600" }, { "ID": "547debb6000dea61b8c695ba24918fe8", "objCode": "RESVT", "endDate": "2014-02-13T23:59:00:329-0700", "startDate": "2014-02-13T00:00:00:329-0700" }, { "objCode": "RESVT", "endDate": "2014-02-14T23:59:00:329-0700", "startDate": "2014-02-14T00:00:00:329-0700" } ] }
```

This is a bit bulky and complex but is the only way to do this in the API at this time.